# Best/efficient way to keep data up to date for all users using asp.net 6 web API, flutter and http requests

Tags: flutter, http, asp.net-web-api, concurrency, .net-6.0

I am in a situation, I have an app that uses http requests to get information from my database via web API. My problem is how can I keep my data updated for every user if another user makes a change it will update the UI on all devices. At the moment I use a method to populate a list and call that every time I navigate through the app which I find is very resource draining.

Here is a quick example of what I have at the moment and then I would call this with getAllJobs every time I want to update

```
List<Ticket> listJobTickets = [];
Future getAllJobs() async {
  client.badCertificateCallback =
      ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
  HttpClientRequest request =
      await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("$emulatorHost/Jobs"));
  request.headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
  HttpClientResponse result = await request.close();
  if (result.statusCode == 200) {
    List<dynamic> jsonData =
        jsonDecode(await result.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
    if (listJobTickets.isNotEmpty) {
      listJobTickets.clear();
      for (var i in jsonData) {
        listJobTickets.add(new Ticket(
          i['jobID'],
          i['staffName'],
          i['clientName'],
          i['jobName'],
          i['jobAddress'],
          i['clientContact'],
          i['jobDescription'],
          i['jobDate'],
          i['jobTime'],
          i['status'],
        ));
      }
    } else {
      for (var i in jsonData) {
        listJobTickets.add(new Ticket(
          i['jobID'],
          i['staffName'],
          i['clientName'],
          i['jobName'],
          i['jobAddress'],
          i['clientContact'],
          i['jobDescription'],
          i['jobDate'],
          i['jobTime'],
          i['status'],
        ));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the problem is that http is only a one way communication therefore the API wont trigger any information to the app when a user changes something.
Any guidance, Information resources will be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a silent Push Notification or Firebase Realtime Messaging to update the App's contents.